# Как Spring генерирует реализацию интерфейса-репозитория?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-jpa

Есть такой интерфейс:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends Repository<User, Long> {

  List<Person> findByEmailAddressAndLastname(EmailAddress emailAddress, String lastname);

  // Enables the distinct flag for the query
  List<Person> findDistinctPeopleByLastnameOrFirstname(String lastname, String firstname);
  List<Person> findPeopleDistinctByLastnameOrFirstname(String lastname, String firstname);

  // Enabling ignoring case for an individual property
  List<Person> findByLastnameIgnoreCase(String lastname);
  // Enabling ignoring case for all suitable properties
  List<Person> findByLastnameAndFirstnameAllIgnoreCase(String lastname, String firstname);

  // Enabling static ORDER BY for a query
  List<Person> findByLastnameOrderByFirstnameAsc(String lastname);
  List<Person> findByLastnameOrderByFirstnameDesc(String lastname);
}
```

Расскажите, пожалуйста, **как Spring–у удаётся сгенерировать реализацию этого интерфейса при компиляции программы**? В репозитории на Github я не смог найти эту логику, как это всё происходит.
Желательно, подскажите справочники, с помощью которых я смогу создать что-то подобное — буду благодарен.

Comment: Это называется магия spring. Если очень коротко, то через рефлексию, создание прокси объекта и перехват выполнения метода.

Comment: Я ожидал развернутого ответа.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239299/spring-aop-proxy-object